# How can I use "MQTT protocol with Kafka as a broker"?

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt

I want to implement a chat application which uses **"MQTT protocol"** in order to send messages from the device(Android phone). I need a **"Kafka broker"** which would run on the server and listen to these messages.
For this, I need an MQTT proxy, but even after googling a lot I could not find any **open source MQTT proxy**. Please suggest if there is an open source MQTT proxy. And if not, then, is it possible to implement one of my own?

Comment: That sounds like a strange requirement: Why do you need MQTT together with Kafka? Keep in mind that Kafka is not a (typical) message broker but can be understood as a distributed log.

Comment: Also asking for recommendations for software is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [MQTT Proxy from Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-mqtt-proxy/), but it is not open source. You can use it free against a single broker, or 30-day trial for a cluster of more than one broker.